# How to create a C-language function returning two or more OUT parameters for postgresql?

Tags: c, postgresql, out-parameters

I need to return two arrays of integers in a C-language function for postgresql. Afaik, the best way to return two arrays of integers in a postgresql function is to declare the function with OUT parameters. But how to return two output parameters in a C-language function for postgresql? Should I return a tuple of two strings containing brace representations of the arrays?

Comment: Does it have to "return" the value? If not you could just send the modified structures back via the parameter list

Comment: @Mike It does not actually matter, but how can this be done? Should I send two empty arrays as IN-parameters?

Comment: Could you clarify a little more what you're looking for? Looks like you'd like more than just C functions updating the parameters. Could you explain why it needs to be a return and not just an updated parameter list? What format are you looking for the data in for the postgresql statement?

Comment: @Mike Postgresql does not seem to keep track of the parameters given to its functions, i.e., even if I pass two arrays as parameters to a postgresql function, they remain unchanged after the function call. Format I am looking for is something like this: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func(IN param1 int, IN param2 int, ... OUT param1 int[], OUT param2 int[]) LANGUAGE C STRICT;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return tuple of two arrays. In reality Postgresql's function returns only one parameter every time. It is relative complex task, but it is possible. You can find some examples - google keyword is PG_RETURN_HEAPTUPLEHEADER